# Matching the font in a scanned doc with the font's character map and doing an OCR (kind of)

Tags: text, scanning

Hopefully I am understandable and don't sound impractical when I ask the above question. To elaborate: I have some scanned documents and the font used in those documents(images) is **FrenchScript MT Std Regular**. I installed that font on my sys. Now I was wondering if it's possible to use the character map of that particular font and match each individual character in the image (the scanned image is just plain text, no images, no paragraphs or no formatting) with font characters and place the matching letters just above the character in the image.

Want to do it in MS word or any other text editors where after the characters are placed above the image, it can be deleted from the background and the document can be saved. It's another type of OCR I guess. How can it be done? Attaching the image to help you understand the scenario.

[image: the source scanned doc]

Comment: Sounds like fairly typical OCR. Have you searched for "trainable OCR"?

Comment: I am with Andrew, since this is printed it should be reasonably possible with a good OCR. What have you tried? Have you tested some of the programmes available out there?

Comment: @boblet I did try with some programs and being OCR programs they are doing their job but not very accurate in the output. They are mistaking the tails of letters for commas and periods and many more such mistakes. Cuz there are so many pages, I can't really afford to recheck each page and that would be really tedious. Do you think the Tesseract-OCR would be of any help here? How are they used? And plz don't forget the main question.

Comment: I am not an expert on this _at all_, but my professor used a programme with reasonable success some years ago; on old, handwritten documents both in latin and arabic. I will see if I can find it, I _think_ it was Tesseract. As to your wishes of an overlay functionality - I have no idea if that can be automated (you could always do it "manually" with the image "behind" your actual text.

Comment: Since your Q is about an overlay functionality; I will just give some pointers to the first leg: how to get text from image: my professor used Tesseract, he trained it (you can train it on different fonts). This is possible by ICR (intelligent character recognition). See this FAQ: https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3 Further; for you overlay-idea, my only suggestion is to do this after conversion, putting the image behind the text, and then quite easily visually check errors.

Comment: @boblet I tried by training some softwares like Abbyy Finereader and the output was not very accurate. Here's the link for the original scanned doc http://imgur.com/SQszjJU .What do you think? Do you think the resolution of the doc is the culprit here? And I have never used Tesseract before. Will learn if it will help. Can you try some tricks on this image using Tesseract or anything else?